# Org-mode logbook: how to thange the structure in the first line of each log?

Tags: org-mode

Emacs org-mode can add LOGBOOK entries to headlines, for instance to task headlines.

[image]

or more generally, to a plain text headline

[image]

In the two examples the first line in each log entry consists of a text with fixed formate, and these were, respectively,

```
- State "<new state>" from "<former state>"    [yyyy-mm-dd day HH:MM] //
```

and

```
- Note taken on [yyyy-mm-dd day HH:MM] //
```

How can I change the structure and fixed text of the first line in each log entry?

For instance, I would like to change the position of the date+time entry from the end to the start of the line, like this

```
   - [yyyy-mm-dd day HH:MM] State "<new state>" from "<former state>"    //
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You can customize `org-log-note-headings` to change some of these templates.